# In a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$, find a complete and linearly independent sequence $(x_k)$ which is not a Schauder basis.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, schauder-basis

this is one of the problems I found in a book I'm studying:

In a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$, find a complete and linearly independent sequence $(x_k)$ which is not a Schauder basis.

With it, there is a hint that reads: contruct $x_k$ so that it converges to some nonzero vector in $\mathbb{H}$; show that such sequences are never Schauder bases.

I have no idea where to start. I tried taking any $x\in\mathbb{H}\setminus\{0\}$ and taking a sequence which converges to $x$, but then what? I can't even guarantee that such a sequence will be complete and linearly independent (in fact, I can't even imagine how it can be linearly independent, since it will eventually get arbitrarily close to $x$). Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: we say that a sequence $(x_k)\subset\mathbb{X}$ is complete if $\forall x\in\mathbb{X}$ and $\forall\varepsilon>0$ there exist $a_k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $||x-\sum_{k=1}^n a_kx_k||\leq\varepsilon$. The coefficients $a_k=a_k(\varepsilon)$ may depend on $\varepsilon$ in this case.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Sorry, forgot to explain that. Edited my question.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili But the hint says that it should be a sequence converging to a nonzero vector. And no, I haven't done this as I have no idea how to.

Comment: My bad, I misread. But the same hint applies: consider some Shauder base that you know and try to modify it so that you obtain a new sequence which converges to some non-zero vector, and it is still complete. Complete essentially means that the linear span of the sequence is dense in $\mathbb H$, so a way of modifyinf a Schauder basis to obtain something that is still complete is by performing operations that leave the linear span of the sequence invariant

Comment: $x_k=e_1+\frac {e_{k+1}} k$ where $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili and geetha290krm Okay, using your hints I got a sequence $x_k=e_1+\frac{e_k}{k}$. This sequence converges to $e_1$. The problem is, I think this is still a Schauder basis. If we have $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_ke_k$, then the same $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}ka_kx_k-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}ka_kx_k$. I can still represent every $x\in\mathbb{H}$ as a unique sum with coefficients of $x_k$. That's the definition of a Schauder basis. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Wait, I think I get it. It isn't a Schauder basis, because the coefficients grow in size and are unbounded. Is that right?

Comment: The unboundedness of the coefficients is not a problem, the definition of Schauder basis does not require the coefficients to be bounded. If that is a Shauder basis, you would be able to write any $x$ as a *converging series* with $x_k$ and coefficients. What you wrote above is not a converging series, it’s a difference of two series which do not even seem to converge. The question is still unanswered: can you write any $x$ as a converging series $x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b_kx_k$ (and can you do that uniquely)?

Comment: If you don’t know where to start as you said, you should at least make sure you understand all the relevant definitions and write them in your post. It seems to me that you don’t know what is the definition of Schauder basis, this shows little effort from your side and prevents people on this website from writing an answer. This is why we are all giving you hints instead of answering. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960 , https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933 , especially the second link